# Shell Array Cleared for Unknown Reason

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a pretty simple `sh` script where I make a system `cat` call, collect the results and parse some relevant information before storing the information in an `array`, which seems to work just fine. But as soon as I exit the for loop where I store the information, the `array` seems to clear itself. I'm wondering if I am accessing the `array` incorrectly outside of the for loop. Relevant portion of my script:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    declare -a QSPI_ARRAY=()

    cat /proc/mtd | while read mtd_instance
    do
        # split result into individiual words
        words=($mtd_instance)
        for word in "${words[@]}"
        do
            # check for uboot 
            if [[ $word == *"uboot"* ]]
            then
                mtd_num=${words[0]}
                index=${mtd_num//[!0-9]/}    # strip everything except the integers
                QSPI_ARRAY[$index]="uboot"
                echo "QSPI_ARRAY[] at index $index: ${QSPI_ARRAY[$index]}"

            elif [[ $word == *"fpga_a"* ]]
            then
                echo "found it: "$word""
                mtd_num=${words[0]}
                index=${mtd_num//[!0-9]/}    # strip everything except the integers
                QSPI_ARRAY[$index]="fpga_a"
                echo "QSPI_ARRAY[] at index $index: ${QSPI_ARRAY[$index]}"

            # other items are added to the array, all successfully

            fi
        done
        echo "length of array: ${#QSPI_ARRAY[@]}"
        echo "----------------------"
    done
```

My output is great until I exit the for loop. While within the for loop, the `array` size increments and I can check that the item has been added. After the for loop is complete I check the `array` like so:

```
    echo "RESULTING ARRAY:"
    echo "length of array: ${#QSPI_ARRAY[@]}"
    for qspi in "${QSPI_ARRAY}"
    do
        echo "qspi instance: $qspi"
    done
```

Here are my results, `echo`d to my display:

```
    dev:    size   erasesize  name

    length of array: 0
    -------------
    mtd0: 00100000 00001000 "qspi-fsbl-uboot"

    QSPI_ARRAY[] at index 0: uboot

    length of array: 1
    -------------
    mtd1: 00500000 00001000 "qspi-fpga_a"

    QSPI_ARRAY[] at index 1: fpga_a

    length of array: 2
    -------------

    RESULTING ARRAY:
    length of array: 0
    qspi instance:
```

**EDIT**: After some debugging, it seems I have two different `array`s here somehow. I initialized the `array` like so: `QSPI_ARRAY=("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g")`, and after my for-loop for parsing the `array` it is still a, b, c, etc. How do I have two different `arrays` of the same name here?

Comment: Your shebang, if it is used at all, needs to be `#!/bin/bash`. `/bin/sh` does not support arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure:

```
cat /proc/mtd | while read mtd_instance
do
...
done
```

Means that whatever comes between `do` and `done` *cannot have any effects inside the shell environment that are still there after the `done`*.

The fact that the `while` loop is on the right hand side of a pipe (`|`) means that it runs in a subshell.  Once the loop exits, so does the subshell. And all of its variable settings.

If you want a while loop which makes changes that stick around, don't use a pipe.  Input redirection doesn't create a subshell, and in this case, you can just read from the file directly:

```
while read mtd_instance
do
...
done </proc/mtd
```

If you had a more complicated command than a `cat`, you might need to use process substitution. Still using `cat` as an example, that looks like this:

```
while read mtd_instance
do
...
done < <(cat /proc/mtd)
```

In the specific case of your example code, I think you could simplify it somewhat, perhaps like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
QSPI_ARRAY=()
while read -a words; do␣
  declare -i mtd_num=${words[0]//[!0-9]/}
  for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    for type in uboot fpga_a; do
      if [[ $word == *$type* ]]; then
        QSPI_ARRAY[mtd_num]=$type
        break 2
      fi
    done
  done
done  </proc/mtd
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this potentially what you are seeing:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024